# How to convert the string "0xAp-2" to double of 2.5, using a std library function

Tags: c++, floating-point, hex, notation, scanf

I have a string containing "0xAp-2". I want to convert that to a double value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    char array[] = "0xAp-2";

    double a;

    sscanf(array, "%lf", &a);

    std::cout << a << "\n";
}
```

I've tried both atof and sscanf, and can't get it to work. I apologize if the answer is obvious, but I've already tried searching google with terms such as "sscanf" and "floating hexadecimal".

Comment: What is the array[] string?  Is it equivalent to 0xA0 + (p-2) ?

Comment: It's weird C notation for A (hex 10) to the power of -2. So divided by 4.

Comment: Your code works fine for me using gcc 4.5 on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: @Truncheon - your code works for me, on Ideone anyway (gcc-4.3.4). http://ideone.com/XSPjp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [`strtod`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) function should be able to parse binary scientific notation.

Answer (score 1):

If anything is going to do it, the `%A` or `%a` format from C99 should do the job.